# Cant send Json String by xmlhttprequest from client to Nodejs Server, using POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, post, xmlhttprequest

Im fairly new at JS and Nodejs and I've been stucked for 3 days trying to achieve this ==>

Send jsonstringified body to server through:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>
    JavaScript | Sending JSON data to server.
  </title>
</head>
<body style="text-align:center;" id="body">
  <h1 style="color:green;">
    Post Product
  </h1>
  <p>
  <form action='/' method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Product Name">
    <input type="text" id="price" placeholder="Price">
    <button id="btn">Send JSON</button>
    <p class="result" style="color:rgb(6, 177, 6)"></p>
  </form>
  <script>
    let button = document.querySelector("#btn");
    button.addEventListener("click", sendJSON, true);

    function sendJSON() {
      let name = document.querySelector("#name");
      let price = document.querySelector("#price");
      let url = "localhost:4000";
      let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 201) {
          result.innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
      };
      const json = [{name: name, price: price}];
      xhr.open('POST', url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/json');
      alert(xhr)
      xhr.send(JSON.stringify(json));
    }
  </script>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

And getting the data on the server side through:

```
const express = require('express')
const routes = require('./routes/routes');
const cors = require('cors')
const server = express()

server.use(express.json())
server.use(cors())
server.set('view engine', 'ejs')
server.set("views",__dirname + "/views")

server.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log('http server on 4000 port')
});

server.post('/', function(req,res) {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(req.params)
    console.log(req.body)
});

server.get('/', function(req, res) {
    var path = require('path');
    res.sendFile(path.resolve('index.html'));
  });
```

But all what I get from console(req.body) and console (req.params) is {} {}, I still dont know if the json is being sent and not received, or not even being sent. I've already tried tons of advices about cors and jsonparsing on server-side but nothing of that seems to work. I would be glad to any suggestions on how to get this done, and even better know the problem behind of what I'm doing wrong. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check the network tab on Chrome Developer tools. Is the body being sent?

Comment: @ArielAlvarado it says status: (pending) and 1 error "Failed to load the resource, server responded with 404 not found"